# How to get cluster statistics for more than 30 minutes in Kubernetes Dashboard?

Tags: kubernetes, metrics, kubernetes-dashboard, kubernetes-metrics

After configuring Kubernetes Dashboard in cluster we are able to get cluster statistics. But we are unable to get data for more than 30 minutes. We need to get all statistics from the start of pods. What settings do we need to configure?

Consider the following screenshot,
[image]

As we can see from the above screenshot, we are able to get only 15 minutes data. Though our pods are running for more than 2 days, we are only getting 15 mins stats.

Need help to get stats for the entire pod/cluster activity.

Comment: Note that Stack Overflow is for programming questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will not be able to see more data without a solution such as Prometheus/Grafana and the different types of exporters.